# apache php-fpm - max_children reached -> server unresponsive until php-fpm restart

Tags: php-fpm, apache-2.4, mariadb

One of our servers with a very special setting is very sensitivee to an unknown event.

Hardware:

- Xen - VM
- 22 Cores (build with Intel xeon 4*6 Core)
- raid 6 SSD
- 60 GB RAM

Configuration:

- Suse Openlinux 13.1
- Apache2.4 - event
- PHP 5.5.14
- mod_proxy_fcgi
- php-fpm
- 5.5.33-MariaDB

Workload:

- arround 120 different Websites
- arround 60 out of the 120 are Typo3-Sites (The rest is also php-driven)

**The issue:**

But sometimes, as an example, when we have a backup job including mysqldump running, we have the problem that one after another of the virtualhosts signal a "max_children reached" and stops responding. Of course we do the backup in low traffic times and we would accept a short time "no response" but this deadlock or blockade never ends on its own. Anything is allright after a manual restart of the php-fpm.

The normal behavior of this system even in high traffic times is flawless and lightning fast. Most of the cores are ideling and the other parameters that I know are ok.

Of course there are no hinting logfile entries neither in the message log (except the "max_children reached") nor in any of the apache/vhosts logs. And yes, the memory usage and the open processes increases rapidly.

Did anybody have a setting like ours (I know there are a lot special things inside this monster) and had the same or look-a-like problems and a cool idea how to debug this problems?